# compare array values

Tags: php

I have a string like this, which I need to extract the address from:

```
$string="xyz company 7 th floor hotel yyyy 88 main Road mumbai 400000 this is sample  comapny address 9456  and some other";

$word=str_word_count($string,1,'0...9');
```

Now `word` has each word like `word[0]=xyz`, `word[1]=company`, `word[2]=7`, etc.

I need to compare each value. If the word is a number then I want to save it in a temp variable until I get another number.
For example `word[2]` is 7, so I need to save the values from then until 88 in a temp variable. So the temp should contain `"7 th floor hotel yyyy 88"`.

If the temp variable has fewer than 25 characters then we compare until we get another number. So here we need to keep going from 88 to 400000 and append that to the temp variable.

The temp should finally look like this: `"7 th floor hotel yyyy 88 main Road mumbai 400000"`

Any help please?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very reliable method for identifying an address.  Even still, I'd use a regular expression to pull out the string you are looking for.

Comment: After you reach 40000 and the temp variable has more than 25 chars, what happens next?
I suggest to use preg_split with a regex. Something like (^\d+\s+\d+$){1, 25} but I didn't understand exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677932/word-n-gram-algorithm-in-php/1678177#1678177), where I responded. Although `preg_match` does not follow your thought process, it accomplishes the result you're looking for. The only change you've made between that question and this one is the 25 character restriction. This can easily be resolved by accepting 25 characters of any type before checking for the terminating number:

```
preg_match('/[0-9]+.{0,25}[^0-9]*[0-9]+\s/',$string,$matches);
return $matches[0];
```

There is no need to use `str_word_count`. If you insist on using it, say so in the comments and we can try to accommodate a solution using your thought process. However, `preg_match` is likely the most efficient way of accomplishing the whole *task*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`preg_match_all()`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions):

```
if (preg_match_all('!(?<=\b)\d\b+.*\b+\d+(?<=\b)!', $string, $matches)) {
  echo $matches[0][0];
}
```

What this is doing is testing for a sequence of numbers followed by any number of characters followed by another sequence of numbers. The expressions are greedy so the middle pattern (.*) should grab as many as possible meaning you'll be grabbing from the first to the last sets of digits.

There is a lookahead and lookbehind in there to check to see if the numbers are on word boundaries. You may or may not need this and you may or may not need to tweak it depending on your exact requirements.

The above works on the whole string.

If you must (or just prefer) to operate on the words:

```
$start = false;
$last = false;
$i = 0;
foreach ($words as $word) {
  if (is_numeric($word)) {
    if ($start === false) {
      $start = $i;
    }
    $last = $i;
  }
  $i++;
}
$word_range = $words;
array_splice($word_range, $start, $last - $start + 1);
$substring = implode(' ', $word_range);
```

Comment: I believe that `echo $matches[0]` would either print an array index not found exception or the word 'Array'. Since you use `preg_match_all`, you'd have to use $matches[0][0] to get the first match.